# What is happening to my pepper seedlings?

Tags: seedlings, peppers

I grew them indoors for about a month then moved then to new pots. I was careful to not destroy the roots as best I could. I also attempted to "harden" them for a few days when it happened to be fairly overcast. I also made sure they all had true leaves.

Their first day out for 8 hours they looked liked the attached. Some even completely feel over and died. Their stems not even able support their own weight.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhV12.jpg
[image: Picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The leaves of your chilli plant are bleached from the sun.

A plant grown indoors does not “harden” to outdoor conditions.

It is necessary to “harden” a plant to full sun and outdoor conditions over a period of time.

When I move plants outdoors I move them into full shade for one week, then if they appear healthy I move them into part shade (about 4 hours direct sun - no more).

Even then you may observe leaf damage to the plant, however the new leaves will be stronger and adapted to the outdoor conditions.

In your situation I’d recommend placing your young plants into a shady position outside for a week before moving them into sun.

If left in small pots, it may be necessary to water your plants daily.